# JavaScript is not executing in a popup window using ModalPopup ( Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modalpopup

I have created a simple popup window via the object ModalPopup in JQuery Library. 
It's an event to a simple button click evenement.
My problem is that the 'Javascript' in popup window is not running ! even it is perfectly running when I open the popup window as a simple html page.

I have used the following code to creat popup window:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //Change these values to style your modal popup

  var align = 'center'; //Valid values; left, right, center
  var top = 100; //Use an integer (in pixels)
  var width = 520; //Use an integer (in pixels)
  var padding = 10; //Use an integer (in pixels)
  var backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF'; //Use any hex code                                                           
  var borderColor = '#333333'; //Use any hex code
  var borderWeight = 4; //Use an integer (in pixels)
  var borderRadius = 5; //Use an integer (in pixels)
  var fadeOutTime = 300; //Use any integer, 0 = no fade
  var disableColor = '#666666'; //Use any hex code
  var disableOpacity = 40; //Valid range 0-100
  var loadingImage = 'images/loading.gif'; //Use relative path from this page
  var source = 'details_company.html';

  //This method initialises the modal popup

  $(".details_company").click(function () {
    modalPopup(align, top, width, padding, disableColor, disableOpacity, backgroundColor, borderColor, borderWeight, borderRadius, fadeOutTime, source, loadingImage);
  });
});
```

I appologize for my bad english.

Comment: wow , you did all that before looking at the jquery site for an example of a modal dialog ?

Comment: You're missing the definition of modalPopup. How are we supposed to help? Where's the JS that's not running? Errors on the console? Please make sure your questions contain more details

Comment: this JS is not running: <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="bouton" onClick="alert('this script is not working')">

Comment: it's not executing and not depending on how JS looks like that's why it's not mentionned. thx

Answer (score 1):

just take a look on this jquery-ui [modal form](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) example. it is simple and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".details_company").click(function () {
  $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
    height: 140,
    modal: true
  });
});

<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
  <p>Adding the modal overlay screen makes the dialog look more prominent because it dims out the page content.</p>
</div>
```

This uses jquery-ui

Comment: i didn't work in phone ( this is a phoneGap application ) besides i need to add a new page containing a form in the popup window. thx